# Difference between a function and a statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, semantics

In class we were asked to name several PL/SQL functions and state their use. Someone mentioned CREATE FUNCTION and I noted that Oracle labeled this as a statement and not a function.

I am unable to give a very good answer on the difference between the two. I am thinking that a statement is more of a declarative tool that specifies what the program is to accomplish whereas a function seems more procedural, we define the procedure for a new function in the CREATE FUNCTION statement.

The distinction seems clearer for something like a SELECT statement, can someone help with a clear delimitation between the two?

Answer (score 1):

A statement is a piece of code that executes. It is a command. It does something. Example:

print "Hello World"

A function is a block of code that you call with parameters and it returns a value (even if that value is undefined). Example:

function(a) { return a * 2 }

Answer (score 1):

The word "statement" has two different meanings in SQL and PL/SQL.

In a narrow technical sense, `CREATE FUNCTION` is a type of SQL statement, and `CREATE FUNCTION` contains PL/SQL statements.

In the more general sense, a SQL statement is declarative code that tells the database "what is true" or "what has to be done", without detailed instructions on "how to do it".  A function, or any PL/SQL block, is imperative code that tells the database exactly "what to do".  Declarative SQL is usually simpler and faster than imperative PL/SQL so it's usually best to do most of the work in SQL and just glue it together with PL/SQL.

---

SQL has about 170 commands (as defined by `V$SQLCOMMAND`), organized into about 31 statement types, organized into [the below 6 categories](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF30001).  The `CREATE FUNCTION` command is a `CREATE` statement type in the `DDL` category.  That classification scheme is not 100% clear from the database and manuals, but I've used it to [thoroughly classify all SQL statements](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/statement_classifier.pck).

> ```
> Data Definition Language (DDL) Statements
>
> Data Manipulation Language (DML) Statements
>
> Transaction Control Statements
>
> Session Control Statements
>
> System Control Statement
>
> Embedded SQL Statements
> ```

---

In PL/SQL, most [blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/block.htm#LNPLS01303) are a sequence of statements.  These statements could be an assignment, loop, fetch, block, etc.

[image]

---

To make things more confusing, in 12c a SQL statement can contain PL/SQL statements:

```
with function f return number is begin return 1; end; select f from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you, can you say something about how a 'function' is different than an SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE FUNCTION` is a statement. The function itself is a `FUNCTION`. Running the statement that creates the function allows you to access the function.

In general, if you're creating anything in the database, you are using a statement (in particular, a data-definition language (DDL) statement). The item you create, be it a table, function, package, etc., can then be referenced in future statements.